# If $\forall Y [(Y\subseteq X \wedge Y\sim X) \rightarrow Y=X]$, then $X$ is finite.

Tags: set-theory

Definitions:

- $X \sim Y$ iff there exist a bijection $f : X \rightarrow Y$
- $X$ is finite if there exist a bijection $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N}_n = \{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$

What I want to prove:

> $\forall Y [(Y\subseteq X \;\wedge\; Y\sim X) \rightarrow Y=X] \Rightarrow  X$ is finite.
>
> This is, given a set $X$ such that the only equivalent subset to it is itself, then $X$ is finite.

My book says this proof needs the Axiom of Choice. I've tried a proof by contradiction but I can't get nowhere. And if I try a direct proof I don't know even where to start...
At this point, I know about ordinals and finite ordinals, but not much about cardinals because this is on the preamble for that.
If you want more context, this is the material I am using:  [Teoría Axiomática de Conjuntos](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/depto/public/grado/fascgrado8.pdf)
(Page 35, after Corollary 2.4.11)

Comment: Contrapositive. If $X$ is not finite then it is non-empty. Take an element $x_0$. Since it is not finite this is not the only element. Take another $x_1$. Keep going ... You get a sequence of different elements $x_0,x_1,...$. Now that you have a sequence of elements construct $Y\subset X$ to be $X\setminus \{x_0\}$. Show that that $Y$ falsifies the left hand side of the implication. Use $f:X\to Y$ defined by $f(x_i)=x_{i+1}$ for the elements in the sequence and identity on the rest.

Comment: The Choice was the sequence $x_1,x_2,...$ that is an element of the set $X\times (X\setminus\{x_1\})\times (X\setminus\{x_1,x_2\})\times ...$.

Comment: But in this context, if I say $X$ is not finite, it doesn't mean is infinite. It just means there is no $n \in \omega$ such that $X \sim n$.

Comment: Infinite literally means not finite.